How to get a payment details using session flow without using `sessionId` & `sessionResult`?
I am planning to use session flow for simplicity but I can't find any documentation regarding how to get payment details without using sessionId & sessionResult using the reference provided on creating the session.
So I am creating a session
// Adyen Go API Library v9.3.0
import (
  "context"
  "time"
  "github.com/adyen/adyen-go-api-library/v9/src/common"
  "github.com/adyen/adyen-go-api-library/v9/src/adyen"
  "github.com/adyen/adyen-go-api-library/v9/src/checkout"
)
// For the live environment, additionally include your liveEndpointUrlPrefix.
client := adyen.NewClient(&common.Config{
  ApiKey:      "ADYEN_API_KEY",
  Environment: common.TestEnv,
})

// Create the request object(s)
amount := checkout.Amount{
  Currency: "EUR",
  Value: 1000,
}

createCheckoutSessionRequest := checkout.CreateCheckoutSessionRequest{
  Reference: "YOUR_PAYMENT_REFERENCE",
  Mode: common.PtrString("hosted"),
  Amount: amount,
  MerchantAccount: "YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT",
  CountryCode: common.PtrString("NL"),
  ThemeId: common.PtrString("AZ1234567"),
  ReturnUrl: "https://your-company.com/checkout?shopperOrder=12xy..",
  ExpiresAt:  func() *time.Time { t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2023-05-18T10:15:30+01:00"); return &t }(),
}

// Make the API call
service := client.Checkout()
req := service.PaymentsApi.SessionsInput().IdempotencyKey("UUID").CreateCheckoutSessionRequest(createCheckoutSessionRequest)
res, httpRes, err := service.PaymentsApi.Sessions(context.Background(), req)

Then passing the /sessions response includes the URL (url) for the Hosted Checkout page to the customer. How can I get the details of this session/payment using the reference later without the notification webhook?
I have tried with their documentation(https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/sessions-flow/?programming_language=go) and example code(https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-golang-online-payments).

You can retrieve the payment result using the /sessions/{sessionId}?sessionResult=... endpoint, you'll have to provide the sessionId in the path parameters and you'll have to provide the 'sessionResult' in the query parameters, see API Explorer or see function in Go Library (v10.4.0): GetResultOfPaymentSession(ctx context.Context, r PaymentsApiGetResultOfPaymentSessionInput) (SessionResultResponse, *http.Response, error

Thanks @Kwok I really appreciate your support but I need to get the details without using sessionId and sessionResult as mentioned in the questions. Because in my flow before generating the payment menu I need to check whether the payment was paid and I can get the sessionId and sessionResult only when the customer is redirected from the session hosted page. So technically I can say if I don't get sessionId and sessionResult then it's in unpaid state but I want to explore are there anything in the documentation I am missing. Thanks again for your help.

I understand now, if you don't get the sessionId or sessionResult the payment will be in your aforementioned unpaid state. You'll still need to get the payment outcome somehow (through the /sessions/{sessionsId}/sessionResult endpoint, see https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/sessions-flow/?platform=Web&integration=Hosted+Checkout&tab=java_2#step-5-get-the-outcome) or you'll have to wait for the webhook (see: https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/sessions-flow/?platform=Web&integration=Hosted+Checkout&tab=java_2#step-5-get-the-outcome).
